# MySQL query that adds values from two columns and groups by a third

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a query using mySQL in PHP that takes two table columns and adds them together and then grouping the result using a third column.

The PHP is for presenting the data in JSON format.

For example, if I have the following data:

[image]

I expect the following JSON response:

```
[
    {"name": "Jake","Value": " $25.50 "},
    {"name": "Mary","Value": " $14.05 "}
]
```

This is my work so far, I don't understand what the right syntax is for summarizing the values of two separate columns:

```
$sql =  "SELECT name, 
        sum(Value1,Value2) as VALUESUM
        from TableName
        group by name
        Order by VALUESUM DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

based on your expected  result seem you need  an addition between the two columns for each row ( and not the sum )

```
    SELECT name, 
    Value1 + Value2  as VALUETOT
    from TableName
    Order by VALUESUM DESC
```

otherwise if you want  the sum for each name  the you could use

```
    SELECT name, 
    sum(Value1 + Value2 )  as VALUESUM
    from TableName
    GROUP BY name 
    Order by VALUESUM DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is this

```
  $sql =  "SELECT name, 
    sum(Value1,Value2) as VALUESUM
    from TableName
    group by name
    Order by VALUESUM DESC";

  //Fetch the rows from table
  $result = $dblink->query($sql);

  //Initialize array variable
  $jsondata = array();

//Fetch into associative array
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
  $jsondata[]=$row;
 }

//Print array in JSON format
echo json_encode($jsondata);
```

This would give you json data of your sql results.
Of course you have to adept the code with your  own variables